# Strtok in reading a string from a text file

Tags: c

I have been trying to tokenize a string from a table using `strtok` but it isn't working.

the table in the text file has this format (only an example), delimited with tabs

```
Jane Doe     iPhone 6     nj-34-k4-3j-jk
```

I want to get the third element but it's not working.
This is what the function looks like

```
scanf("%s", filename);

fp2 = fopen(filename,"r");

if (fp2 == NULL){                                               
    printf("Error reading File \n");
    exit(1);                                                    
}

//while reading a line, keep getting tokens (a line)
while ( fgets ( str, sizeof(str), fp2 ) != NULL )               
{ 
    token = strtok(str,"    ");
    token = strtok(NULL,"   ");
    token = strtok(NULL,"   ");

    if(index>0){                                                
        strupr(token);                                          
        strcpy(address[index-1], token); //store in array                   
    }       

    index++;                                                    
}
```

Comment: Do you mean real tabs (`'\t'`) or some number of spaces (`' '`) to align by "tabs"?

Comment: @MikeCAT yes real tabs ('\t')

Comment: The second argument to `strtok()` should have a `\t` (tab) as one of the characters. It might or might not also hold a newline `\n` too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler tried it but the program stopped working

Comment: You’ve not shown how `address` or `index` are defined and initialized. You aren’t checking the return from `strtok()`; you aren’t showing the line read before ``strtok()`` mangles it or what `strtok()` returns.  The code isn’t an MCVE ([MCVE]). It is hard to guess what’s going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Use tabs to have it split by tabs.

```
token = strtok(str,"\t");
token = strtok(NULL,"\t");
token = strtok(NULL,"\t");
```

Comment: Only the first line works, getting the first element. If I add the 
    'token = strtok(NULL,"\t");
    token = strtok(NULL,"\t");'
the program will stop working.

Comment: @chelsey [The code should work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hOWYarDq2WaKODgp). Please give us [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you have white spaces mixed with tabs, then `const char *delim = " \t"; strtok(str, delim);strtok(NULL, delim);...`

Comment: @MikeCAT thank you so much for your effort, just fixed it and strtok(NULL,"\t") worked too! :)

Comment: @Pablo Thank you so much for mentioning that, I checked the text file and found out that it is mixed with spaces. Thanks, again!